# Is BigQuery job history data available as metadata?

Tags: google-bigquery, metadata

Is BigQuery job history data available as a meta-data table in BigQuery? Or is the REST API the only way to get job history?

I'd like to inspect and count jobs run in a window of time. Via the REST API this means inspecting all jobs for all time and filtering as the list is scanned as the `filter` option for the API only supports filtering on `labels.key` at present (see [ref](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/labels#filter-syntax)).

Doing this all in SQL against a meta-data table would be much preferred.

Comment: check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant that looks promising. Thank you!